# Vue JS - vue-class-component binding input

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently working on a Vue 2 project with TS using these libraries for component setup : `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`

I need to create a form component, but I'm having a hard time with data binding, because when I use the data() option for my form component it produces errors on compile time.

Is there a way to bind input data without using the data() option ?

The errors I get :

**`ERROR in /path/to/components/folder/Form.vue`**

```
Property 'id' does not exist in type 'Form'.
```

For more context here's my code :

```
@Component
export default class Form extends Vue {
//Bind form data
data() {
    return {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        age: 0,
        amountA: 0,
        amountB: 0,
        capitalA: 0,
        capitalB: 0
    } 
}

onSubmit(e: any): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Create new class object
    const newClass = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name,
        age: this.age,
        amountA: this.amountA,
        amountB: this.amountB,
        capitalA: this.capitalA,
        capitalB: this.capitalB
    }

    //Emit the class object to parent component
    this.$emit("add-class", newClass);
    this.$emit("update-total");

    //Reset Form
    this.id = ""
    this.name = ""
    this.age = 0
    this.amountA = 0
    this.amountB = 0
    this.capitalA = 0
    this.capitalB = 0

}
```

And here's the error on my console: [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYIFm.png)

Can anyone helps me to get ride of these error. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue class component decorators, the Options API's `data()` function is abstracted away.

The `@Component` decorator is a function responsible for transpiling your code from Class API syntax into Options API syntax.

Namely, behind the scenes:

- all class props are turned into `data()` reactive props,
- all getters/setters are turned into `computed` props
- all class methods (regular functions) are turned into `methods`.

So just declare the props directly on the class instance:

```js
@Component
export default class Form extends Vue {
  id = "";
  name = "";
  age = 0;
  amountA = 0;
  amountB = 0;
  capitalA = 0;
  capitalB = 0;

  // props declared above are reactive and you can now use them
  // in getters or methods
}
```

See the example in the [Overview](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) page. In more detail, this particular comment:

> // Class properties will be component data

---

**Warning:** If you're just picking up Vue, be warned Vue class decorators syntax is on a downwards usage trend and problems with Vue 3 compatibility are to be expected (and have already started to surface). Have a look at the open issues on their repo.

On the same note, you might want to read [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4744#issuecomment-937369062) by Evan You<sup>**1**</sup>, ref usage of Vue class component decorators:

> It definitely isn't a recommended option anymore in official docs or default tooling (moving to Vite-based soon and vue-cli will be in maintenance mode).
> Deprecation will depend on actual usage and **@ktsn**'s<sup>**2**</sup> intention on further working on the project.

**<sup>1</sup>** :: author of Vue
**<sup>2</sup>** :: maintainer of `vue-class-component` package

---

Personal advice: installing [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) in your Vue 2 project and rewriting its components in Composition API syntax would be more beneficial than writing in class decorators syntax, to both yourself and the project.

In doing this, you'll

- make it possible for the project to be upgraded to Vue 3 with relative ease
- learn Composition API (likely to become the more common Vue syntax), which is more valuable for you, going forward, than learning the component class decorators syntax and workarounds, (likely to become less used, eventually deprecated)

Because the class decorators syntax is dropping in popularity, the support for it might become more difficult to obtain, as time passes.

If rewriting existing components in Composition API is not an option, you could at least write new components in this syntax, as the syntax is incrementally adoptable, it can be used alongside any other valid Vue API syntax.

Comment: Hi tao, first I would like to thank you for enlighten me! I will definitely take a closer and deeper look on the topic.
I really appreciate all the details and the explanation.
Finally, I did refactor my code and it works perfectly fine, like you said I have been mixing up the vue conventional way and the vue component way.